# Table data is disappearing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to populate a table with PHP script data using jQuery. I am trying as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/test.php",
                type:"POST",
                async:true,
                data:{
                    "done":1,
                    "searchDat" : searchDat,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    //alert( JSON.parse(data));
                    var array = JSON.parse(data);
                    var trHTML = '';
                    $.each(array, function(ind,value) {
                        console.log(value);
                        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + value+ '</td></tr>';
                    });
                    $('#Table').append(trHTML);
                }   
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="Table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>ID</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ID2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Button**

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id ="button" style="width:50%;border-radius:8px;padding: 15px 4px;"/>
</form>
```

The problem is that the table is populated for 1 second and then disappears in the webpage. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/bbcprg/getPrograms.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: {
      "done": 1,
    },
    success: function(data){
        //alert( JSON.parse(data));
        var arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(arrayData, function(ind,value) {
            console.log(value);
            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + value+ '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#Table').append(trHTML);
                }   
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: First of all use `$('#Table').find('tbody').append(trHTML);`

Comment: Is the `#button` element `type="submit"`? If so, then your form is also being submit and the page is refreshing itself.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai It did not work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  think you are right. The page is refreshing. What should I do in place of `submit`?

Comment: In that case select the `form` element and hook to the `submit` event, but be sure you call `preventDefault()` on the event. If you're still unsure, update your question to include the form and button HTML and I'll show you how to do it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan See the updated question

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you've attached the event to the `click` of the `button`. This means that while your AJAX request works, the `form` is still being submit, and hence the page gets refreshed.

To fix this, hook to the `submit` event of the `form` instead, and call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to the handler. Try this:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/test.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: {
      done: 1,
      searchDat: searchDat,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var html = data.map(d => '<tr><td>' + d + '</td><td>' + d + '</td></tr>').join('');
      $('#Table tbody').append(html);
    }   
  });
});
```

Also note that you can simplify the logic which builds the HTML to append by using `map()` on the `data` array. You also don't need to manually call `JSON.parse()` if you specify the correct `dataType` on the `$.ajax` request. I've also assumed that `searchDat` is defined outside the function.

Finally I'd suggest you place an `id` on the `form` to make the selector less generic, and also you should move the inline `style` rules in to an external stylesheet.

Comment: This is not working. I am using your code's modified version. See the Edit1 in question.

Comment: Can you give some more info that simply 'it doesn't work'. What does happen? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope. No error even data is not printing on the console. Not any error on the console

Comment: I tried to add alert as `$("form").on('submit', function(e){
 alert("Enter")`. Even it is not alerting means that it is bit entering inside the `.on('Submit')`

Comment: The document.ready event handler is missing in the second code block. `$(function() { /* code here... */ });`

Comment: Nope. Edit1 is showing the whole code inside script tag.

Comment: Then you need to put the code in one. I only left it out of my answer as it's pretty much a given that jQuery logic has to be placed in one.

Comment: It is giving the same problem now. Table is populating for 1 second and then refreshing the page.... Ahhhhh!

Comment: Got it. I was not printing `e.preventDefaults()`. Now working

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" id ="button" style="width:50%;border-radius:8px;padding: 15px 4px;"/>
```

to this

```
<input type="button" value="Search" id ="button" style="width:50%;border-radius:8px;padding: 15px 4px;"/>
```

Comment: No, do not do this. Having no `submit` button means that you cannot submit the form by pressing the `Return` key on the keyboard, which is vital for accessibility standards.

Comment: @rory-mccrossan yes, you are right. Then you need to prevent the default behavior of submit button and attach ajax call instead.